# How to upload files to remote server using jquery blueimp

Tags: php, jquery, blueimp

I'm working with https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/ Plugin.

How can I setup this plugin so that I can upload a file to a random remote servers.

I have 5 servers with following URL's

1. mydomain.com/files
2. mydomain2.com/files
3. mydomain3.com/files
4. mydomain4.com/files
5. mydomain5.com/files

*More server can be added dynamically when needed.

Do i need to upload the `uploadhandler` class (php) to each server? or what else i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do a couple of things,

first the random server

```
server_pool = ["mydomain.com/files","mydomain2.com/files","mydomain3.com/files","mydomain4.com/files","mydomain5.com/files"];
var theserver = server_pool[Math.floor(Math.random() * server_pool.length)];
```

now we are going to add our random server to de main.js file inside blueimp.

Replace this

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'server/php/'
});
```

For this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    // url: 'server/php/' OLD ONE
    url: theserver
});
```

Now is time to the PHP Part, You need to upload the server/php folder to all the other servers but first you need to add this to the index.php file inside them.

Add this right after  the

this is the result:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Example 5.14
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

first upload the file to the main server and then send it to the server you want with curl

```
$curl_connection = curl_init('http://serverX.exemple.com/upload');
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);  

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'upload' => '@' . "path/to/file1.ext",

    ));

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo curl_exec($curl_connection) ;
curl_close($curl_connection);
```